# Why does Perl's DBI complain about "failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate" when I try to connect to Oracle 11g?

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

I am getting the following error connecting to an Oracle 11g database using a simple Perl script:

```
 failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at
```

The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

if ($#ARGV < 3) {
print "Usage: perl testDbAccess.pl dataBaseUser dataBasePassword SID dataBasePort\n";
exit 0;
}
my ($user, $pwd, $sid, $port) = @ARGV;

my $host = `hostname`;
my $dbh;
my $sth;
my $dbname = "dbi:Oracle:HOST=$host;SID=$sid;PORT=$port";

openDbConnection();
closeDbConnection();

sub openDbConnection() {
        $dbh = DBI->connect ($dbname, $user ,$pwd , { RaiseError => 1}) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
}

sub closeDbConnection() {
        #$sth->finish();
        $dbh->disconnect();
}
```

Anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: John, when you do get this fixed, please remember to come back here and "accept" your favourite answer.  If you have to modify something for your environment, you can even post *that* solution and accept it, and then "up-vote" the answers that helped you get there.  This will properly retire the question for the SO archives.

Answer (score 7):

Check your Oracle client configuration (including, as the message says, ORACLE_HOME), check file permissions, etc. It's unlikely that DBI per se has anything to do with the problem, and I know for a fact that DBD::Oracle is compatible with the 11g libraries (at least the 11g InstantClient).

Comment: [Exhaustive troubleshooting information](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Oracle/) - start with the files `README` and `README.help.txt`.

Comment: If I set ORACLE_HOME to the 10g instance, it's able to connect to the 11g database, however if I set ORACLE_HOME to the 11g instance I get the error...

Comment: OK so ORACLE_HOME is changed, if there are references to the 10g binaries in your PATH are you resetting those also to their 11g counterparts as well?

Comment: Don't just change ORACLE_HOME to point to a different oracle client library WITHOUT rebuilding DBD::Oracle - it most likely won't work properly. When you build DBD::Oracle is examines the header files and client to see what version you have and builds a DBD::Oracle appropriate for your client libraries. There are a load more reasons too many to put in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

- Install the perl module [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.52/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm)
- Add `use DBD::Oracle;` into your perl script.

This made the problem go away for me.

Answer (score 2):

Afther upgrade Oracle form 10.2.0.4 to 10.2.0.5 my Perl-CGI not working, the error.log file of Apache was the error:

> DBI connect('DB','user',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check
>   ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings,
>   permissions, etc. at ...
>   OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows)
>   and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.! at ...

adding the following directive solve the problem:

```
my $ORACLE_HOME = "/usw/app/oracle/product/10.2";
$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}=$ORACLE_HOME;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for bringing this thread alive again, but I've been trying to solve this issue for weeks. Nowhere did I find that what finally solved it for me.

Environment: RedHat 6.5, Oracle Instant Client 12.1, Apache 2.2

**What solved it for me:**
Change the permissions of the directory where Oracle Instant Client is installed., which must also be the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The directory wasn't accessible to "other", just owner and group. This command made the whole difference:

```
# chmod o+rx INSTANTCLIENT-DIRECTORY
```

I had been trying to create every possible combination of ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. (Even "unsetting" ORACLE_HOME; I found suggestions that would solve the issue, since Instant Client needed only LD_LIBRARY_PATH and !NOT! ORACLE_HOME.) Nothing helped, until ... 
it hit me to look further in the error message:

```
    failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var
    or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.
```

**permissions** being the key word!

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Please add a little more explanation to make the solution clear.  Some of our citizens aren't fluent in English, such that leaving the answer implied may not lead them to a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Added some more text to the actual solutions. I was so eager to share this when I found the problem. So I probably wasn't too educational =)  Feel free to change it further if you think that is missing information.

Comment: For me the solution was part of what you wrote here: I just needed to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path to the instant client directory.

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Update for CentOS 8 etc:-**

If you use systemctl, nothing in your environment or Apache setup can pass environment vars to DBI!

you need to edit the /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service file and add appropriate lines like this after the [Service] section:

```
[Service]
Environment=ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1
```

Then re-start apache as usual:-

```
/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
```

(Vote this up if it helped you: this web page is the #1 google result for this old problem which systemctl "security" has rebirthed)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `#!/usr/bin/perl` (first line of your script) is the right perl version you wish to use too !

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers don't solve this problem, but they did point me in the right direction: The launched environment was missing the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Oracle instantclient. You can check by calling: `launchctl export`

or

`launchctl getenv variable_name` in OS X 10.10

I compared the output from my .bash_profile and found that the path to instanclient wasn't in `launchctl PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` - Once I added them with the following it worked:

```
launchctl setenv PATH /path/to/instantclient
launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/instantclient
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable used to specify the Oracle libraries may be different from one system to another.  On most systems, use LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it may also be LIBPATH (notably on AIX), DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, or maybe others.

Answer (score 0):

I too went through the same issue. In my case ORACLE_HOME environment variable was incorrect.